# PHP post_max_size overrides upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, upload, filesize

In my site host, I have seen (via phpinfo) that

- post_max_size = 8Mb
- upload_max_filesize = 16Mb

This led me to think that I should be able to upload as file as big as 16Mb.
However, when I do this through a post method (as normal), post_max_size takes over and declares that I sent too much.

What is the method which permits sending a file as big as 16Mb ?
GET - PUT - other ?

Hope someone can clarify this for me.

Simon

Answer (score 110):

`upload_max_filesize` is the limit of any single file.
`post_max_size` is the limit of the entire body of the request, which could include multiple files.

Given `post_max_size = 20M` and `upload_max_filesize = 6M` you could upload up to 3 files of 6M each. If instead `post_max_size = 6M` and `upload_max_filesize = 20M` then you could only upload one 6M file before hitting post_max_size. It doesn't help to have `upload_max_size` > `post_max_size`.

It's not obvious how to recognize going over `post_max_size`. `$_POST` and `$_FILES` will be empty, but `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` will be > 0. If the client just didn't upload any post variables or files, then `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` will be 0.

Answer (score 21):

By POST file uploads are done (commonly, there are also other methods). Look into the method attribute of the form which contains the file-upload field ;)

The lowest limit of any related setting supersedes a higher setting:

- [post_max_size](http://php.net/post_max_size)
- [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/upload_max_filesize)
- [memory_limit](http://php.net/memory_limit)

See [Handling file uploads: Common Pitfals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) which explains this in detail and how to calculate the values.

Answer (score 18):

The normal method to send a file upload is POST, thus also `post_max_size` should be 16 Mb or more.

Incidentally, also `memory_limit` plays a role. It should be bigger than 16Mb, but since the default value is 128Mb, you won't see this problem. Example `php.ini` configuration:

```
post_max_size = 16M
upload_max_filesize = 16M
memory_limit = 128M
```

Change these value in `php.ini` if you've access to it, otherwise you can try to change them in an `.htaccess` file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
php_value post_max_size 16M
```

This will work only if the `AllowOverride` settings permit it. Otherwise, you've to ask to your hosting company.

Answer (score 17):

#### **post_max_size:**

- Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload
- To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize
- Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size.
- *PHP Default: 8M*

#### **upload_max_filesize:**

- The maximum size of an uploaded file
- *PHP Default: 2M*

---

### memory_limit > post_max_size > upload_max_filesize

#### PHP Default: 128M > 8M > 2M

By default, post_max_size should be 4 times greater than upload_max_filesize.
 In turn
memory_limit should be 16 times greater than post_max_size

Answer (score 8):

Your server configuration settings allows users to upload files upto 16MB (because you have set [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/upload_max_filesize) = 16Mb) but the [post_max_size](http://php.net/post_max_size) accepts post data upto 8MB only. This is why it throws an error.

Quoted from the [official PHP site](http://php.net/post_max_size):

> 1. To upload large files, post_max_size value must be larger than upload_max_filesize.
> 2. memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size

You should always set your post_max_size value greater than the upload_max_filesize value.

Answer (score 3):

change in php.ini `max_input_vars   1000`

Comment: This is not a relevant answer to the question. max_input_vars sets how many input variables may be accepted, not the total size of their values.