# PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 53160843 bytes exceeds the limit of 33554432 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mamp

I got a small problem. When I try to uploads some big size images I get above error. But If I try to upload same size images using Drag and Drop method, I can upload all files. I have checked some similar solved problems. But could not understand how can I check and modify php.ini file.  How can I solve this problem?  I am using Mac OS and MAMP Server.

Answer (score 0):

line no:770 to change php.ini

post_max_size = 1000M

refer:

[PHP post_max_size overrides upload_max_filesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754133/php-post-max-size-overrides-upload-max-filesize)

Comment: Thanks for help first. I have changed Post_max_size to 1025M and upload_max_filesize = 1024M and memory_limit =1025M but still same problem.

Comment: No use. Now I have set Post_max_size to 1025M and upload_max_filesize = 1024M and memory_limit =128M but still not working.

Comment: Do you think should I restart the server after change.

Comment: Yes, you must always restart the server after updating php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Change or add the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` fields in the applicable `php.ini` file e.g.

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

You can find the location of the file by creating a PHP file with contents:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then restart your server, navigate to the page in your browser and search for the `Loaded Configuration File` value.