# Changing post_max_size to 512M not being affected on WAMP

Tags: php, laravel

I have read other answers here on stackoverflow, however this is a really weird issue.

My phpinfo() shows that I have set 512M for the post_max_size (I have also increased other properties to at least 512M)

However when I am trying to send post request from Angular HTTP to Laravel 5.2 api, I get 422 Unprocessed Entitym and php_error says:

`PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 7323588 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

I have changed both php.ini files,despite only one being loaded.

Comment: Did you set it locally or globally

Comment: @shabany make sure your restart your Apache server after making changes

Comment: Yeah I did that, WAMP Restart All, that's the weird thing. I told you that it does show under phpinfo(), just not being affected on the actual runtime

Comment: Is you website onlin e? can you please show your phpinfo() to us

Comment: make a new php file and echo phpinfo();

Comment: It is a localhost  http://screencast.com/t/niKdxBrbMWf

Comment: @Uchiha I went to php.ini and changed it. Then restarted WAMP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7754160/2899618

Comment: @shabany Make Sure upload_max_filesize should be changed in both php.ini files.. In the Apache folder, and the PHP folder

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Go to the folder destination where you have installed WAMP. (Usually it is C:)

**Step 2**: Now locate and open php.ini files from both these locations. (C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin and C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16)

**Step 3**: Now in both the documents press CTRL+F and find out the following settings.

- post_max_size
- upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit

For example you will see upload_max_filesize = 2m where m is MB. Change 2m to 500m or more as you like.

Change post_max_size = 8m to post_max_size = 700m or more. Change memory_limit = 8m to memory_limit = 1000m.

Other than that to avoid fatal errors like maximum time of something exceeded in line something, find and change the following values.

max_execution_time = 30 to to max_execution_time = 3000 and max_input_time = 60 to 3000.

[image]

Comment: I can see this change. Maybe it is something to my Angular HTTP call to LAravel 5.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting problem.

The issue was following:

Yes, I needed to change the `post_max_size`, however at one point in my `php.ini` I had it set to `1000M`.

My Apache 2.4.9 , and PHP 5.5.12 decided to ignore the suffix `M` and I ended up with a limit of `1000 Bytes`.

My solution was to set `post_max_size = 1000000` to have the limit set to `1MB`