# Upload failed with error code 1 in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I made changes into `php.ini`, setting

```
upload_max_filesize = 2000m 
post_max_size = 800M
```

and I'm getting an error:

> Upload failed with error code 1 in php

If I upload images then it works fine but for larger files it shows me above error code of php file upload.

Restarted xampp several times, and even restarted my PC also.

Comment: How large are the files that fails? Do you have any max size in the actual form?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i want to upload videos using php. it work for small files like images .docs file but not work for videos.

Comment: no i didn't set any kind of validation into it.

Comment: But, _how large_ are the files that fails? The file type is irrelevant. And your `post_max_size` needs to be at least the same, or even bigger, than your `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP post\_max\_size overrides upload\_max\_filesize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754133/php-post-max-size-overrides-upload-max-filesize)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry for getting late but upto 2MB

Comment: @MagnusEriksson in my script user upload only single file at a time he wont open multiple file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

**set post_max_size = upload_max_filesize = 200M(or 800M) will resolve this issue(remember restart apache)**