# Is there a maximum setting for Upload_Max_Filesize Limit in php

Tags: php, file-upload

Is there an upper limit for Upload_Max_Filesize?

For example, can it be set to 50G assuming you are acting as your own host and have control of the server?

I don't know who marked this as a duplicate or why as it isn't. I asked if there is an upper limit for the directive, not **how** to do it.

Comment: The dupe link looks rather informative / relevant to me.

Comment: Informative or not - it doesn't answer the question. Not even close.

Comment: For your question of is there an upper limit -- it seems moot because you specifically want to know about 5G files.  Are you receiving more than 10 files of this size in the batch? As for "can it be set...?" I believe this is what @FunkFortyNiner is trying to offer with the dupe link. This also looks informative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7754316/2943403 Please don't perceive my comments as attacks.  I am sure Funk is trying to be helpful as well. Perhaps you might add some more details about your specific task to add context to your question.

Comment: @mickmackusa I added your link above as another duplicate. I can't see how this post should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on web server as well.
Here is more about limitations (in case you are using Apache): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody
Please also pay attention to `post_max_size` setting.

Anyway: i would suggest you to upload big files by chunks, it's more relay way. In case of network error you need to re-upload just chunk, not whole file.
HTML5 file API allows to get access to file and implement uploading it by chunks, you can also easely implement upload progress.

Comment: Here's the correct answer: There is no actual limit to the value you assign this parameter. Practically, however, if you were to increase the size you run a security risk of people uploading huge files - tens of gigabytes in size - causing your resources to disappear. See, not a duplicate question in any way.