# Ajax upload issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to build a tool on my own website that allows me to upload 50-100 images to my webserver. I been working on this for 1-2 weeks. The problem is, it uploads then it stops all of the sudden and "this.status" = 0 instead of = 200. And then my entire website stops working for like a minute like there's some type of overload.

It was important to have a progress bar. So at first my code uploaded multiples files at the same time which I thought it might be a problem. So I changed it to only upload 1 at a time. Still issues!

```
<input type="file" multiple id="file-input" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
<button onclick='The_Function_to_upload();'>Upload</button><br>

<script>

offset_test = 0;    // this is the offset of what file to upload
max_files = XXX;    // how many files there are. This is populated correctly

function The_Function_to_upload (){ // this function is called when pressing "Upload"
        
    upload_image(offset_test);      // This uploads the FIRST FILE ONLY!
        
}

    
function upload_image(i_filen) {


    var files = document.getElementById("file-input").files;    // get the file we're uploading

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", files[i_filen]);    // add the file
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "upload.php", true);     // the PHP that uploads

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {     // call on request changes state
      
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            var response = this.responseText;
            if(response == "File uploaded successfully"){           // if PHP file outputs "File uploaded successfully", it means file was uploaded
               
                offset_test +=1;        // increase the offset to next file
                                
                if (offset_test==max_files){ 
                    alert('completely done');   return;     // ALL DONE. END
                }
                upload_image(offset_test);                  // upload next file
                
          }else{
                alert("File not uploaded: " + response);
           }
         }
      };

      xhttp.send(formData);       // Send request with data

}

</script>
```

You can view my own created log at the bottom.

I even changed the PHP file to only output "File uploaded successfully" so it doesn't even upload. It still stops.
I also added a setTimeout to wait 1.5 SECONDS before it calls function upload_image AND **IT STILL stops** for gods sake. I have no idea why this is happening. Obviously it must be a server problem. But what can I do? :S  Please guys, please help me :(

```
phpinfo() settings:
post_max_size: 128mb
memory_limit: 512mb
max_execution_time: 999999999
max_input_time: 999999999
upload_max_filesize: 1gb
max_input_vars: 1000
```

--

```
1. this.readyState:     2
2. this.status:     200
3. this.readyState:     3
4. this.status:     200
5. this.readyState:     4
6. this.status:     200
7. File uploaded:   1   (this means 1st is uploaded)
    
8. this.readyState:     2
9. this.status:     200
10. this.readyState:    3
11. this.status:    200
12. this.readyState:    4
13. this.status:    200
14. File uploaded:  2   (file 2 has been uploaded)
    
    ...
    etc
    ...
    
15. this.readyState:    2
16. this.status:    200
17. this.readyState:    3
18. this.status:    200
19. this.readyState:    4
20. this.status:    200
21. File uploaded:  41  (this means 41 files been uploaded)
   Now try to upload file # 42.
22. this.readyState:    4  (why does this not show 2 and then 3 and jumps to 4 ?)
23. this.status:    0     (why does this show 0 instead of 200 ? )
```

And here it stops! and sometimes at this point, my ENTIRE website stops working for 30-60 seconds :/ Sometimes it stops at file 43..but it's usually after 40 files it stops.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49549458/3132019) is the issue.

Comment: Please ad you php code.

Comment: @Grumpy the PHP code only displays "File uploaded successfully", that's it. I disabled the upload for now for testing purposes.

Comment: @Gerard I edited this post and added the phpinfo() settings. I have the highest setting on it. Any ideas? :/

Comment: @Maria I presume the upload.php does more then just displaying "File uploaded successfully", dont you process the uploaded file?

Comment: @Grumpy yes it originally did. But since it froze after around 40 files were uploaded, I turned of the uploading part cause I thought maybe the upload was putting stress on the server so now the php file ONLY outputs "File uploaded successfully".  But it seems that made no difference what so ever. So either the problem is doing a POST to PHP file too many times? I have no idea and the php limit settings are pretty high so I have no idea why this is happening. But the entire website not working for few seconds after I run the script indicates it's an overload situation :/

Comment: The website appearing to lockup/freeze after multiple iterations over a client-side recursive function indicates a memory-leak in the JavaScript. You most likely need to move functionality out of the recursion into the global scope instead.

Comment: Another possibility could be web-server connection configuration related, such as in Apache the `MinSpareServers MaxSpareServers StartServers` being too low or too high depending on the server resources. We'd need to know more about the environment and the configuration.