# Laravel Image upload not working when the file is big

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-upload

Cannot upload big files to laravel
I am trying to upload image from vue js , when the file size is less than 1mo it is working but when it exceed , laravel return 400 error bad request I already checked if it is from vue but it is with laravel the error, i already use storage but it is still not working Does anyone know how to solve this ?

```
  public function store($id,Request $request)
    {
    if(!$request->hasFile('image')) {
        return response()->json(['upload_file_not_found'], 400);
    }
    $file = $request->file('image');
    if(!$file->isValid()) {
        return response()->json(['invalid_file_upload'], 400);
    } 
    $path = Storage::putFile('logements', $request->file('image'));
    return response()->json($path);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is laravel, and not apache or nginx?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754133/php-post-max-size-overrides-upload-max-filesize

Comment: already changed my php.ini file but no changes